# How to fix fatal: Access denied for user A by PAM account configuration [preauth]?

Tags: centos, sshd

Updated openssh to sshd 8.1. Error connecting to server: sshd fatal: Access denied for user A by PAM account configuration [preauth]
Configured ldap, authorization by key.
I don't understand what's wrong, can't connect to the server? not by key, not by password.
I work through a long-open connection in the terminal.
Distro Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.7"

Comment: If you've still got that long-open connection, look in the server's `auth.log` or equivalent, where the sshd service writes its detailed error messages. You should get a better reason for the login refusals

Comment: @roaima I get error:  error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: If you no longer have the long-running connection you described then you're going to find some other way of logging in to the server. You are very very unlikely to be able to resolve this without access to the server.